# How to extend a 3rd party directive and add custom logic in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and Typescript and I wish to override the uploadImage function from [ngx-summernote](https://github.com/lula/ngx-summernote/blob/33c36644ad2f9a8760577fb2790d2bef165b87c0/projects/ngx-summernote/src/lib/ngx-summernote.directive.ts) directive. I tried to extend the class, but I get error `'Class 'CustomNgxSummernoteDirective' incorrectly extends base class 'NgxSummernoteDirective'.Types have separate declarations of a private property 'uploadImage''.`

Here is my extended directive code.

```
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[ngxSummernote]',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomNgxSummernoteDirective),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CustomNgxSummernoteDirective extends NgxSummernoteDirective {

  private async uploadImage(files) {
    if (this._options.uploadImagePath) {
      
      this.imageUpload.emit({ uploading: true });

      const requests = [];
      for (const file of files) {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('image', file);
        const obs = this.http
          .post(this._options.uploadImagePath, data)
          .pipe(
            map(
              (response: { path: string }) =>
                response && typeof response.path === 'string' && response.path
            )
          );
        requests.push(obs);
      }

      this.uploadSub = combineLatest(requests).subscribe(
        (remotePaths: string[]) => {
          for (const remotePath of remotePaths) {
            this._$element.summernote('insertImage', remotePath);
          }
          this.imageUpload.emit({ uploading: false });
        },
        (err) => this.insertFromDataURL(files)
      );
    } else {
      this.insertFromDataURL(files);
    }
  }
}
```

Please let me know if this is feasible to do, if so what change I have to do in derived class. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `uploadImage()` is really private you can't override it. Is it possible to do the different logic in your own method and then call the provided `uploadImage`? And then also process the result in suitable way?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to capture error during upload which is missing in ngx summernote and don't think I can do it in my derived class and call uploadImage. If not feasible I will look for an alternative packages then. Thanks